# Concatenate ascii/org tables with some different headings

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, data-manipulation, zshrc

I want to concatenate two ascii tables (one below the other) that share some but not all column headings, and I want to replace "blanks" with some string, like "nan" in the output.  (related: [can we do this with emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21357/concatenate-ascii-org-tables-with-some-different-headings), but no answer as of yet)

e.g.

Table 1

```
Head1 HeadA
1     a
2     b
```

Table 2

```
HeadA HeadFoo
c     bar
```

And the result would be

```
Head1 HeadA HeadFoo
1     a     nan
2     b     nan
nan   c     bar
```

I have written the following very fresh zsh script (uses one zsh-only command) but it is **slow** when there are lots of columns (for obvious reasons).

Note that above I use tab-delimited examples, but my script expects space-delimited tables.

```
#!/bin/zsh
#
# take several dat files, possibly with different headers
#
containsElement () {
  local e
  for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}


ALL_COLUMNS=()

for A in "$@"; do
  if [ ! -f ${A} ]
  then
            echo not a file
            exit
    fi
    ALL_COLUMNS=("${ALL_COLUMNS[@]}" `head -1 "${A}"`)
done

typeset -U ALL_COLUMNS

echo $ALL_COLUMNS

for A in "$@"; do
    HEADER=($(head -1 "${A}"))
    TMP="_TMP_${A}_"
    TMPFILE="_TMPFILE"
    #create empty temporary files (/hack)
    touch "${TMPFILE}"
    touch "${TMP}"
    rm "${TMP}"
    rm "${TMPFILE}"
    touch "${TMPFILE}"
    touch "${TMP}"
    for C in ${ALL_COLUMNS[@]}; do
        if ! containsElement "${C}" "${HEADER[@]}"
        then
                "${C}" not in "${HEADER[@]}"
                #paste a column of nans to TMPFILE
                paste "${TMP}" <(sed '1d;s/.*/nan/' "${A}") > "${TMPFILE}"
                cat "${TMPFILE}" > "${TMP}"
        else
            # echo "${C}" is in "${HEADER[@]}"
            #find which column this is, cut it, and paste it to TMPFILE
            COUNT=1
            for H_KEY in $(head -1 ${A}); do
                if [ "${C}" = "${H_KEY}" ]; then
                        break
                else
                    let COUNT=COUNT+1
                fi
            done
             paste "${TMP}" <(cut -d " " -f${COUNT} <(sed '1d' ${A})) > "${TMPFILE}"
            cat "${TMPFILE}" > "${TMP}"
        fi
    done
    #cat the current input file to stdout, with any additional nan columns.
    #remove leading white space left by paste
    sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//' "${TMP}"
    rm "${TMP}"
done
```

Edit: Here are two more input files (space delimited this time) to try.

```
 % cat test1.dat
A B C
1 2 3
 % cat test2.dat
A B D
1 2 4

 % ./collate_dat_files_different_headers.sh test2.dat test1.dat

A B D C
1   2   4   nan
1   2   nan 3
```

And here is a bigger set of inputs (note the space delimited inputs if you are trying this out on your own script.):

```
 % ROWS=10; (echo A B C D E F G && seq $ROWS > _tmp && paste _tmp _tmp _tmp _tmp _tmp _tmp _tmp | sed 's/\t/ /g') > bigtest.dat
 % cat bigtest.dat
A B C D E F G
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7
8 8 8 8 8 8 8
9 9 9 9 9 9 9
10 10 10 10 10 10 10

 % cut -d" " -f1,2,5,7 bigtest.dat > bigtest1.dat
 % cut -d" " -f1,2,4,7 bigtest.dat > bigtest2.dat
 % cut -d" " -f1,2 bigtest.dat > bigtest3.dat
 % cut -d" " -f7,6,4,2,3,1 bigtest.dat > bigtest4.dat

 % ./collate_dat_files_different_headers.sh bigtest1.dat bigtest2.dat bigtest3.dat bigtest4.dat
A B E G D C F
1   1   1   1   nan nan nan
2   2   2   2   nan nan nan
3   3   3   3   nan nan nan
4   4   4   4   nan nan nan
5   5   5   5   nan nan nan
6   6   6   6   nan nan nan
7   7   7   7   nan nan nan
8   8   8   8   nan nan nan
9   9   9   9   nan nan nan
10  10  10  10  nan nan nan
1   1   nan 1   1   nan nan
2   2   nan 2   2   nan nan
3   3   nan 3   3   nan nan
4   4   nan 4   4   nan nan
5   5   nan 5   5   nan nan
6   6   nan 6   6   nan nan
7   7   nan 7   7   nan nan
8   8   nan 8   8   nan nan
9   9   nan 9   9   nan nan
10  10  nan 10  10  nan nan
1   1   nan nan nan nan nan
2   2   nan nan nan nan nan
3   3   nan nan nan nan nan
4   4   nan nan nan nan nan
5   5   nan nan nan nan nan
6   6   nan nan nan nan nan
7   7   nan nan nan nan nan
8   8   nan nan nan nan nan
9   9   nan nan nan nan nan
10  10  nan nan nan nan nan
1   1   nan 1   1   1   1
2   2   nan 2   2   2   2
3   3   nan 3   3   3   3
4   4   nan 4   4   4   4
5   5   nan 5   5   5   5
6   6   nan 6   6   6   6
7   7   nan 7   7   7   7
8   8   nan 8   8   8   8
9   9   nan 9   9   9   9
10  10  nan 10  10  10  10
```

My question: Is there a faster/better way to do this or improvements to my script?

Comment: Have you looked at `paste`, `join`, or `column`?

Comment: I don't think join is what I want, since it will merge tables rather than cat them. paste is in my script above, and column might be helpful in putting things together (as paste is), but I don't see how it will speed the script up.  Good to know about those though.

Comment: Shouldn't the last *Result*  be `nan  c  bar` ??

Comment: Correct.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the following will meet all your requirements for the several files not made part of the question, but for your example files, it does. Whether it is faster or slower, you will need to test. You will need to make a few adjustments as it is written in bash, but the primary purpose was to provide a few additional ideas for how to approach the problem, rather than it being a one-script solution to merge all possible files.

Rather than relying on external utilities, the script makes use of several arrays. First to read the headers from `$1` and `$2` into separate files and scan the header fields for a field to join file1 and file2 on (a common header -- it takes the first found). It saves the (zero-based) join field for file1 in `j1` and the join field for file2 in `j2`.

The remaining lines for each file are read into arrays `alines` and `blines`. The script then iterates through `alines` separating `alines` and `blines` into separate fields (`afields` and `bfields`) checking for a common value on the join fields `j1` and `j2`. If found, all values are printed for the common join field, if no common value in the join field is found, `afields` are printed and `nan` is printed in the vacant field from `$2`.

The final set of loops, loops through `blines` essentially doing the same thing for `blines`. However, here when checking for a common value in the join field, if a common value is found, then that line is *not-output* (due to being printed in the iteration of `alines` above.

Essentially both sets of nested loops simply handle all lines in `$1` and any lines from `$2` with a common value in the join field (first set). Then the second set handles lines for `$2` not previously handled in the first set. Hopefully the use of arrays rather than tmp files will speed the operations, but for huge files, the performance of any script will suffer.

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ ! -f "$1" -o ! -f "$2" ] && { ## validate 2 input filenames
    printf "error: insufficient input, usage: %s file1 file2\n" "${0//*\/}"
    exit 1
}

j1=0        ## join field file 1, 2, joined flag
j2=0
joined=0

read -r -a a1 < "$1"    ## read file headers
read -r -a a2 < "$2"

for ((i = 0; i < "${#a1[@]}"; i++)); do     ## find join fields
    for ((j = 0; j < "${#a2[@]}"; j++)); do
        if [ "${a1[i]}" = "${a2[j]}" ]; then
            j1=$i
            j2=$j
            joined=1    ## set found flag
            break
        fi
    done
    [ "$joined" -eq 1 ] && break    ## found - done
done

printf "%-6s" ${a1[@]}              ## print file1 header
printf "%-6s" ${a2[@]:$((j2+1))}    ## print file2 header from j2 on
printf "\n"

oifs="$IFS"     ## save internal field separator
IFS=$'\n'       ## set to break on space

alines=( $(tail -n+2 "$1" ) )   ## read remainder of $1 & $2 into line arrays
blines=( $(tail -n+2 "$2" ) )

IFS="$oifs"     ## reset IFS to original (space, tab, newline)
key=0           ## common key field value flag

for ((i = 0; i < "${#alines[@]}"; i++)); do         ## for each line in $1
    afields=( ${alines[i]} )                        ## separate into fields
    for ((j = 0; j < "${#afields[@]}"; j++)); do    ## for each field
        printf "%-6s" ${afields[j]}                 ## print field
    done
    for ((k = 0; k < "${#blines[@]}"; k++)); do     ## for each line in $2
        bfields=( ${blines[k]} )                    ## check if key fields match
        [ "${afields[j1]}" = "${bfields[j2]}" ] && printf "%-6s" ${afields[j]} &&
        key = 1
    done
    [ "$key" -eq 0 ] && printf "%-6s" "nan"     ## if no match print 'nan'
    key=0
    printf "\n"
done

for ((i = 0; i < "${#blines[@]}"; i++)); do         ## for each line in $2
    printf "%-6s" "nan"                             ## field 1 always 'nan'
    bfields=( ${blines[i]} )                        ## separate into fields
    for ((k = 0; k < "${#alines[@]}"; k++)); do     ## for each line in $1
        afields=( ${alines[k]} )                    ## separate fields
        [ "${afields[j1]}" = "${bfields[j2]}" ] && key = 1  ## check match
    done
    [ "$key" -eq 1 ] && key=0 && continue           ## if match already output
    for ((j = 0; j < "${#bfields[@]}"; j++)); do    ## print $2 fields
        printf "%-6s" ${bfields[j]}
    done
    printf "\n"
done
```

**Input Files**

```
$ cat dat/f1.txt
Head1 HeadA
1     a
2     b

$ cat dat/f2.txt
HeadA HeadFoo
c     bar
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ bash joinarray.sh dat/f1.txt dat/f2.txt
Head1 HeadA HeadFoo
1     a     nan
2     b     nan
nan   c     bar
```

(note: the output is the output that makes logical sense as addressed in my comment to you under the original question)

Comment: I'm struggling to make this work.  Posted input files in OP because no formatting in comments.

Comment: Ah, OK, you threw me a curve-ball with the new data files. In the original files, there was only one-common field between the files, in the new datafiles, just about every field is common between the datafiles. Still doable, but we will have to rework the loop structure to handle multiple matching fields in each data file. You are correct that `join` and `paste` are of no help in this case. You will essentially have to write a parser/joinder to handle each differing set of files (or at least the input routines). I'll have time in a couple of hours to revisit.

Comment: For what it's worth, my script does work, so maybe it's not a rewrite that I need.

Comment: That was what I put in the top of the answer. Not having more datafiles to begin with, I was concerned that there would be a match with the other files you talked about. You may find an approach or two that will help with your current code. One other trick, is to read from 2 file-descriptors in a single loop, that will allow you to open each file and perform a line-by-line analysis on the common fields, etc. If I have anything else that looks like it would help with the additional table layout, I'll post it as a supplement.

Answer (score 0):

Use gnu join and do a "full outer join" on the two tables:

```
%join -a1 -a2 -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1 0 2.2 -e "nan" table1 table2

Head1 HeadA HeadFoo
1 a nan
2 b nan
nan c bar
```

You may wish to pretty up the output with column:

```
%join -a1 -a2 -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1 0 2.2 -e "nan" f1 f2 | column -c3 -t
Head1  HeadA  HeadFoo
1      a      nan
2      b      nan
nan    c      bar
```